# How to simulate a click on the currently highlighted row in a DataTable?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm trying to make the function that runs when I click a DataTable row to also run when I change the values in an HTML select menu. I'm using the `onchange` event in the selector to run the function `reclickRow()`:

```
function reclickRow() {
    $("#mydataTable").DataTable.$('tr.active').trigger("click");
}
```

However this is not having the desired effect. Some other variables should update with the new value from the selector but they stay the same right now. They only update if I manually reclick the row but I don't want the user having to do that.

Comment: When reclickRow executes is there actually an active selected row in the table? Maybe perform a console.log($("#mydataTable").DataTable.$('tr.active').length)  and double check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @Rex Hendersons's tip, I figured out that I should be referencing the selected row and not the active row:

```
function reclickRow() {
    mydataTable.$('tr.selected').trigger("click");
}
```

Its working now!

Comment: just to make it clear, there is actually no active row at the moment when the function is running.